# FCM failure message: InvalidParameters

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In some FCM messages that I'm sending, as the response I'm seeing a failure error with the message 'InvalidParameters' but I can't find any documentation about the meaning of this error.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

There isn't anything about that exact message. Is it something that's beign sent wrong in the push request or is something else?

Comment: happens to me too when sending a notification to a Firefox client

Comment: To firefox OS? Hadn't thought about that... I thought that the FCM service was SO independent...

Comment: To Firefox browser. The FCM service is not completely platform agnostic, some parameters can vary, although most of them are the same... (see tables 2a/2b/2c in your link)

Comment: This is happening for me in a nodejs app. I've followed the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging -> Build Send Requests, but it doesn't work and the docs are inadequate.